# changing the color ov two div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with this script I would like to `mouseover` a menu item and **change the background color** and also change the color of another div at a timing of 2000. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".block-menu").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#97D8E6'}).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css({'background-color' : '#43BDCB'});
        }); 
        $(".sections1").css({'background-color' : '#97D8E6'}).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css({'background-color' : '#43BDCB'});
        });     
    });
});
```

Comment: The point of stackoverflow isn't to give you answers on how to do things. We *can* point you in the right direction though. Have you looked at the docs for jquery hover (https://api.jquery.com/hover/)? That might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To (2000ms) **`.animate()` the background** of an element you'll either need **jQuery UI** or dynamically toggle classes (using jQuery) that uses CSS3 `transition` - in order to apply your fancy fade background transition:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".block-menu").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("jQhover");
    // $(".sections1").toggleClass("someClass");
  });

});
```

```css
.block-menu{
  height:200px;
  background: #43BDCB;
  transition: background 2s; /* or use: 2000ms */
}
.block-menu.jQhover{ /* This classs is toggled by jQuery on hover */
  background: #97D8E6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block-menu">HOVER ME to animate my BG to a lighter color</div>
```

The above uses jQuery just cause I suppose you want to do something with `$(".sections1")` since in CSS you can only target child elements or next siblings... otherwise, you can simply use CSS:

```
.block-menu{
  height:200px;
  background: #43BDCB;
  transition: background 2s; /* or use: 2000ms */
}
.block-menu:hover{ 
  background: #97D8E6;
}
.block-menu:hover .someChild{ 
  background: red;
}
.block-menu:hover + .nextToBlock-menu{ 
  background: blue;
}
.block-menu:hover ~ .allNextSiblingsToBlock-menu{ 
  background: blue;
}
```

without jQuery.